# Controlling the order of a stacked bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I know there are several questions on the general topic of ordering bars in stacked bar charts in ggplot2, but I have not found one relevant to this issue.

Here's my example:

```
d <- data.table(q=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), p=factor(c('W', 'W', 'W', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'I', 'I', 'I'), levels=c('W','C','I')), pct=c(0.4, 0.3, 0.45, 0.5, 0.4, 0.35, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2))
```

My objective is a stacked bar chart were q is the x-axis variable, and the pct values are stacked. I want the order of the stack to correspond to the values in p, in the order W, C, I.

```
ggplot(data=d) + geom_bar(aes(x=q, y=pct, fill=p), stat='sum')
```

gives the wrong result; the sort order in each stacked bar seems to be determined by the values in pct.

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=q, y=pct)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=p), stat='sum')
```

gives the desired result. Hooray! But, I want to format my graph further; specifically, I want to format the labels of the y-axis. But

```
ggplot(data=d) + geom_bar(aes(x=q, y=pct, fill=p), stat='sum') + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

results in a different sort order. I cannot figure out how to achieve my desired sort order and format!

Package version: ggplot2_2.0.0

Comment: you didnt make sure your reproducible example worked first

Comment: You may want to review your examples, the first and second are the same code, and all three have stacks with different order for each bar.

Comment: For me all your examples produce the same figure (`ggplot2_2.1.0`). Which `ggplot` version do you use?

Comment: Sorry folks, I have now corrected the 2nd example, which gives the desired answer.